# InitialisingComponent Error being thrown (Visual Studio C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have asked this question a couple of days ago and really did not get any help on it. So i am going to re-ask the question in a more better sense. I am doing a fully automated speech recognition program. I have the program complete but one error. This error happens to be the InitializingComponent(). see code below:

```css
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
```

in the program i have 2 winforms (using C#) that uses the same events and methods. Once i do the Form frmEdit, I then can change the class name to all the same for example this is the breakdown:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
public partial class AlarmClock : Form
public partial class Commands : Form
```

ok i originally changed Form1 : Form to frmMain : Form.
this form contains all the events, methods, constructors etc., etc.,

With the Form Edit option i can edit the form names. So i changed the other two with the same public partial class name. So now all three are frmMain : Form.

However i have no errors anywhere in the program except this error that is on the frmMain (Form1) and the error says:

Error   1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:

```
'Ivan.frmMain.InitializeComponent()' and 
'Ivan.frmMain.InitializeComponent()'
C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Ivan Assistant\Ivan\Ivan\Form1.cs
```

I have pasted the exact error. So i have done this program before, then scratched it and started over and so forth.

What do i need to do to correct this error. If you need to see more code then i can make a video and post it on youtube for you to see. I really don't want to start all over again but that is neither there nor here. This program is eventually going to be going out for testing once i can get this error resolved and see if it will debug.

This is about as plain as i can explain this with out the ability to post pictures at the moment. But like i said i can do a video and explain what i am doing. If that would help anyone.

Comment: please edit this question and provide all relevant code to your question.. the code snippet stuff does nothing which defeats the case in  regards to what you are trying to depict in reference to the error's / Issues that you are currently experiencing

Comment: The error message says that InitializeComponent is declared multiple times. Review all frmMain partial classes, check this, and remove the duplicate code. BTW: usually Visual Studio uses two partial classes - one for auto generated code and one for your code. It is a bit strange that you have three partial classes for frmMain

Comment: did you watch the video link that was posted

Comment: @Uranus  here is a link to my question. I had actually posted another question about this today and put a video link to it but here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bVNBY7lARw

Comment: The cause of the error is demonstrated in your video at 2:07. As I said, you have too many declarations of the InitializeComponent method in the same class. This is what about the compiler error message says.

Comment: @Uranus So how would i go about in correcting it?

Comment: Give a unique name for each Form class. What you wanted to achieve by renaming all classes to frmMain?

Comment: if i changed them again with all the code would it affect the program since its already coded

Comment: @Uranus i don't think that would work. I changed the public partial class name on the AlarmClock and it gave a lot of errors. I have to do it some way where all the forms that a frmMain is pulling the methods off Form1.cs